# Merge overlapping WhatsApp backups

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I flashed my phone last year, but before that, I made a WhatsApp backup. However, the WhatsApp backup made wasn't complete(perhaps I exited the app while backing up). Hence, I lost 1 year worth of chat history.
I have an old phone which still retains the chat history, but the chat histories are overlapping, as described below:

- Old phone chats: 2015(month unknown) - June 2018
- New phone chats: 2016(month unknown) - present

I would like to merge the chat histories (and preferably, call logs too) to contain the chats from 2015 - present. I have seen many WhatsApp backup merging tutorial and posts like in [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-merjapp-merge-whatsapp-databases.2896496/), but these only explain how to merge the backups if the chat histories do not have overlapping chat histories. How do I merge two overlapping chat histories, without causing messages from 2016-2018 to appear twice?

I only need to know how to merge the `wa.db` and  `msgstore.db` and other relevant files, if I need help in retrieving them and altering them I would post it as another question.

Thanks.